# parse.com angularjs SPA - equivalent to HTML5 .htaccess

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, parse-platform, routes, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to host an angularjs SPA on parse.com
I haven't uploaded any server code for now (they're just static files!)
https://app.hybridrecruitment.com

The following link will work: https://app.hybridrecruitment.com/#/pages/auth/register
While https://app.hybridrecruitment.com/pages/auth/register will return page not found.

Can you please advise on the cloud code equivalent to this .htaccess?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Send all requests to the index.html unless
    # it's a directory or a file that actually exists
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution by myself. Don't know if it's the most logical. But it works.
Basically on each request I grab and serve the index.html.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
//push state interceptors
var pushUrlPrefixes = [""];
var index = null;

function getIndex(cb) {
    return function(req, res) {
        Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            url: 'my_url_here', // works only in http 
            success: function(httpResponse) {
                index = httpResponse.text;
                cb(req, res);
            },
            error: function(httpResponse) {
                console.log('error');
                console.log(httpResponse);
                res.send("We're very busy at the moment, try again soon:"+httpResponse.text);

            }
        });
    }
}

pushUrlPrefixes.forEach(function(path) {
    app.get("/"+path+"*", getIndex(function(req, res) {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.status(200).send(index);
    }));
});
```